# Bounding the extrema of polynomials from $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \exp(-1/x)$

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics, analyticity, smooth-functions

As laid out on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function), the function
$$f(x):=\begin{cases} \exp(-1/x) & x>0\\ 0 & x\le 0  \end{cases}$$

has the expression for derivatives at $x>0$,
$$ f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{p_n(x)}{x^{2n}}f(x) $$
where the polynomials $p_n$ of degree $n-1$ are recursively defined by $p_1=1$,
$$ p_{n+1} = (1-2nx)p_{n} + x^2 p_{n}'$$

I am interested in bounding $f^{(n)}$ on sets like $[0,a]$. Since its well known that all derivatives vanish at $x=0$, and  $f(x)/x^{2n}$ never vanishes for $x>0$, the local extrema of $f^{(n)}$ occurs at a zero of $p_{n+1}$, so bounding $f^{(n)}(x)$ depends on value of its zeros.

Alternatively, perhaps a crude bound on $p_n$ on these sets $[0,a]$  is obtainable from the recurrence. This sounds easier, but I have yet to make progress here as well.

### Question

How do I get a bound on $f^{(n)}$? (Preferrably one that looks like the inequality below)

### Motivation

to test my understanding of [Gevrey functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gevrey_class), I have decided to check what which space (if any) this function belongs to. This requires getting some bounds on the derivative. My suspicion is that $f$ is Gevrey of order 2, i.e. for any compact set $K$(and in particular any compact set containing $0$) there is a constant $C$ such that
$$ \sup_{x\in K} |f^{(n)}(x)| \le C^{n+1} n!^2 $$

### Notable "similar question"(currently unanswered)

[Bounding $n$-th derivative of $x \mapsto \exp\left({-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030680/bounding-n-th-derivative-of-x-mapsto-exp-left-frac1x2-right)

There is a comment there that reaches somewhat the same idea (the associated recursive polynomial is important) but doesn't say any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of this after typing the question...

Let $p_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} p_{n,k} x^k$. We know $p_{n,0} = 1$ for all $n$. Also, $$p_{n+1,n} =-2n p_{n,n-1} + (n-1) p_{n,n-1} = -(n+1) p_{n,n-1} $$ More generally,
$$ p_{n+1,k} =  p_{n,k}-2np_{n,k-1} + (k-1)p_{n,k-1}$$
(with the understanding that for $k>n-1$ or $k<0$, $p_{n,k}=0$.) Thus
$$ P_{n+1} := \sup_k  |p_{n+1,k}| \le 2(n+1) P_n$$
This means that
$$P_{n}\le 2^{n} n! $$
so 
$$\sup_{x\in [0,a]} |p_n(x)|\le2^n n!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  a^k =\frac{2^n n!(a^{n}-1)}{a-1}$$
Now, recall that for $x>0$, $e^{x} > \frac{x^j}{j!}$. Rearranging,
$$ e^{-x} \le \frac{j!}{x^j}\implies e^{-1/x} \le x^j j! \implies \frac{ e^{-1/x}}{x^{2n} } \le (2n)! \le 4^n n!^2$$
so I'm left with the bound
$$ \sup_{x\in [0,a]} |f^{(n)}(x)| \le C_a^{n+1} n!^3$$
So the function is Gevrey of order 3. Don't know if I can improve it...